# Why some compose keys don't work?

Tags: compose-key

For instance, I can enter a pound £ or yen ¥ symbol, but not a Euro symbol; a copyright © but not trademark, and so on.  All the characters seem to be defined in the system compose file (`/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`), and I can see nothing different about the ones that work vs ones that don't.

I'm running OpenSuSE 13.1 with `fvm2` window manager.  IIRC, setup is just default US English.  Working vs non-working seems to be the same in `xterm`, or in apps like the browser I'm using now.

The output of running `locale; export | grep IM_MODULE` is simply to run `locale`, and then to state `export: Command not found.` The output of `locale` is

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=fr_CH
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

(The `LC_CTYPE` is to make emails in French readable.)  There doesn't seem to be an `IM_MODULE` variable in the environment.  Doing `env | grep IM` gives

```
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
XMODIFIERS=@im=local
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
QT_IM_SWITCHER=imsw-multi
```

But those don't seem relevant, as I'm not trying it with QT or GTK applications.  (AFAIK, I don't know for sure what the browsers use under the hood.)

Comment: Are you working on the same machine or remote logging from another ? If remotely connecting, the Compose keys of the actual system that you are using to connect could be picked up.

Comment: @Amit Kumar: Same machine, not a remote login,

Comment: Going by the characters you list, it seems that you're only getting latin1 characters. In an xterm where this happens, what's the output of `locale; export | grep IM_MODULE`?

Answer (score 2):

The character type `LC_CTYPE=fr_CH` tells X to use ISO-8859-1, which has copyright © and *registered* ® but not *trademark* **`™`**.  Euro, of course, is absent from ISO-8859-1 (that is in a different, later encoding: ISO-8859-15).

In `/usr/share/X11/locale/locale.alias`, you would see this:

```
fr_CH                                           fr_CH.ISO8859-1
fr_CH.88591                                     fr_CH.ISO8859-1
fr_CH.88591.en                                  fr_CH.ISO8859-1
fr_CH.ISO-8859-1                                fr_CH.ISO8859-1
fr_CH.ISO_8859-1                                fr_CH.ISO8859-1
fr_CH.iso885915                         fr_CH.ISO8859-15
fr_CH.ISO-8859-15                               fr_CH.ISO8859-15
fr_CH.utf8                                      fr_CH.UTF-8
```

Further reading:

- [Compose key and xterm vs. UTF-8](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2010-March/213702.html)
- [Unicode Character 'TRADE MARK SIGN' (U+2122)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm)
- [HTML ISO-8859-1 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp)